ESP32 to Google Sheets Data Logging - Stops After a While
I use Google Sheets to log various data received from my ESP32. I'm not an expert in this area, so I’ve adapted some programs from the internet to suit my needs. Below is the program I am using:
ESP32 Program:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "Horticool"; 
const char* password = "horticool@123";
String GAS_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; // Google Script Deployment ID

long gsheet_millis = 0;
float sensor_1, sensor_2, sensor_3, sensor_4, sensor_5, sensor_6, sensor_7, sensor_8,
        sensor_9, sensor_10;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.print("Successfully connected to: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    Serial.println();
}

void sendData(){
    String Send_Data_URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/"+GAS_ID+"/exec?";
    Send_Data_URL += "sensor_1=" + String(sensor_1);
    Send_Data_URL += "&sensor_2=" + String(sensor_2);
    // ...
    // Add all sensors
    Send_Data_URL += "&sensor_10=" + String(sensor_10);
    
    HTTPClient http;
    http.begin(Send_Data_URL.c_str());
    http.setFollowRedirects(HTTPC_STRICT_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS);
    int httpCode = http.GET();
    Serial.print("HTTP Status Code : ");
    Serial.println(httpCode);

    String payload;
    if (httpCode > 0){
        payload = http.getString();
        Serial.println("Payload : " + payload);  
    }
    http.end();
}

void loop() {
    // Generate dummy data
    sensor_1 = random(10, 100);
    sensor_2 = random(10, 100);
    // ...
    // Generate all sensors' data
    sensor_10 = random(10, 100);
    
    if(millis() - gsheet_millis >= 60000){
        gsheet_millis = millis();
        if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
            Serial.println("Not connected to WiFi");
        } else {
            Serial.print("IP address: ");
            Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
            sendData();
        }
    }
    delay(100);
}


Google Script Program:
function doGet(e) { 
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));  // View parameters
    var result = 'Ok'; // Assume success
    if (e.parameter == 'undefined') {
        result = 'No Parameters';
    }  else {
        var sheet_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // Spreadsheet ID
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet_id).getActiveSheet(); // Get Active sheet
        var newRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;                        
        var rowData = [];
        var d = new Date();
        var Curr_Date = Utilities.formatDate(d, "Asia/Dhaka", 'dd/MM/yyyy');
        var Curr_Time = Utilities.formatDate(d, "Asia/Dhaka", 'HH:mm:ss');
        rowData[0] = Curr_Date; // Timestamp in column A
        rowData[1] = Curr_Time; // Timestamp in column B
        
        for (var param in e.parameter) {
            Logger.log('In for loop, param=' + param);
            var value = stripQuotes(e.parameter[param]);
            Logger.log(param + ':' + e.parameter[param]);
            switch (param) {
                case 'sensor_1':
                    rowData[2] = value; // Value in column C
                    result = 'Written on column C';
                    break;
                case 'sensor_2':
                    rowData[3] = value; // Value in column D
                    result += ' Written on column D';
                    break;
                // ...
                // Add all sensors
                case 'sensor_10':
                    rowData[12] = value; // Value in column L
                    result += ' Written on column L';
                    break;
                default:
                    result = "unsupported parameter";
            }
        }
        Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rowData));
        // Write new row below
        var newRange = sheet.getRange(newRow, 1, 1, rowData.length);
        newRange.setValues([rowData]);
    }
    // Return result of operation
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
}

function stripQuotes(value) {
    return value.replace(/^["']|['"]$/g, "");
}


When I send 3-4 variables, everything works perfectly. However, the problem arises when I try to send more data (e.g., 10-15 variables). Initially, a few sets of data are recorded properly, which can vary from 5 to 20 times. After that, the data upload stops, and the HTTP response code is -1. Restarting the ESP32 will make it work again for a short time, but the issue reoccurs.
Sometimes, it doesn’t upload at all, with the response code being -1 from the start. I have checked the execution logs of the Google Script, and there are no errors. It uploads the data if it receives the HTTP request; otherwise, it doesn’t. When the ESP32 stops sending data, there is no record in the Google Script execution log.
Additionally, I tried using the http.POST() method instead of http.GET(). In that case, along with the existing issue, I encountered a new problem. When the data uploads successfully, it shows an HTTP response code 302 (redirect) instead of 200. Then, after a while, it stops uploading just like before.
As I mentioned earlier, I’m not very skilled in this matter. I’ve been trying various solutions for the past few days but haven't been able to resolve the issue. I hope someone can provide a solution.
Thanks in advance.

I suggest, send JSON instead of different parameters.
That will be a much better method, i think
